# Promise {_bitField: 0} in some cases

Tags: promise

I am using Promises using `bluebird`.

When I console.log the value am passing in resolve, I get

`Promise {_bitField: 0}`

in some cases whereas sometimes I get some value apart from 0. I am unable to figure out why is this 0 coming.

Can anybody brief me the meaning of this field, set to be zero.
It gets frustrating. I am new to concept of promises.

**EDIT1**

```
function calculateMinLoanValue(){
      return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
            db.tx(t =>{
            return t.one("select configuration_value from fint.configuration where application_id =(select application_id from fint.application where application_name='Product Tailoring') and configuration_key ='MIN_LOAN_VALUE'")
            })  
            .then(value => {
                   min_loan_value = value.configuration_value;
                   resolve(min_loan_value);
           })
     })
}
```

When I called this function in another function and console.log its output, I got `_bitField: 0`.

Comment: Please provide some context, e.g. the code you are referring to with _"When I console.log the value am passing in resolve"_.

Comment: I only wanted to know its meaning and why does it appear `0`, anyways see the edit.